# displaying image on tkinter python 2.7 widget in my code

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am a beginner in Python, I want to add an image to the widget that I have made with the code below, the display size is 1024 * 600 px / full screen, I use LCD 7 inc. is someone helping me to do that?

```
        import time
        import serial
        from Tkinter import *

        serial_speed = 115200
        serial_port = '/dev/ttyACM0'

        ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, serial_speed, timeout=1)

        class Application(Frame):

            def measure(self):

                 ser.write("m")
                data = ser.readline()

                # If the answer is not empty, process & display data
                if (data != ""):
                    processed_data = data.split(",")

                    self.tegangan_data.set("TEGANGAN: " + str(processed_data[0]))
                    self.tegangan.pack()

                    self.arus_data.set("    ARUS    : " + str(processed_data[1]))
                    self.arus.pack()

                    self.daya_data.set("   DAYA : " + str(processed_data[2]))
                    self.daya.pack()

                    self.torsi_data.set("   TORSI   : " + str(processed_data[3]))
                    self.torsi.pack()

                    self.panas_data.set("   PANAS MESIN : " + str(processed_data[4]))
                    self.panas.pack()

                    self.jarak_data.set("   JARAK TEMPUH    : " + str(processed_data[5]))
                    self.jarak.pack()

                # Wait 1 second between each measurement
                self.after(500,self.measure)

            # Create display elements
            def createWidgets(self):

                self.tegangan = Label(self, textvariable=self.tegangan_data, font=('Verdana', 20, 'bold'))
                self.tegangan_data.set("Tegangan")
                self.tegangan.pack()


                self.arus = Label(self, textvariable=self.arus_data, font=('Verdana', 20, 'bold'))
                self.arus_data.set("Arus")
                self.arus.pack()

                self.daya = Label(self, textvariable=self.daya_data, font=('Verdana', 20, 'bold'))
                self.daya_data.set("Daya")
                self.daya.pack()

                self.torsi = Label(self, textvariable=self.torsi_data, font=('Verdana', 20, 'bold'))
                self.torsi_data.set("Torsi")
                self.torsi.pack()

                self.panas = Label(self, textvariable=self.panas_data, font=('Verdana', 20, 'bold'))
                self.panas_data.set("Panas mesin")
                self.panas.pack()

                self.jarak = Label(self, textvariable=self.jarak_data, font=('Verdana', 20, 'bold'))
                self.jarak_data.set("Daya")
                self.jarak.pack()


             def __init__(self, master=None):
                Frame.__init__(self, master)
                self.tegangan_data = StringVar()
                self.arus_data = StringVar()
                self.daya_data = StringVar()
                self.torsi_data = StringVar()
                self.panas_data = StringVar()
                self.jarak_data = StringVar()

                self.createWidgets()
                self.pack()
                self.measure()
        root = Tk()
        app = Application(master=root)
        app.mainloop()
```

look like this (in link), I want to add an image right below it (in full window)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4pVF.jpg

Comment: You can read about the `PhotoImage` class [here](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Comment: @HenryYik explain more please

Comment: If you want to put several lines of text on top of a background image, better use `Canvas`.  Study `Canvas` manual and it is not difficult to understand.